# Why this odd unupvote occurrence

Tags: support, voting, locked-votes

i haven't been active for a while (around 2 months) on sports stack exchange, just now I noticed -10 points for an unupvote [image]

I'm not exactly sure why this happened. I've never experienced the unupvote before. I also noticed it happened to another question of mine, although I up voted both answers.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you asked this on Meta Stack Overflow; did you mean to ask this on Meta Sports instead, or perhaps [metase]?

Comment: @MartijnPieters seemed like a normal feature in stackoverflow/stackexchange to ask about.

Comment: Sure, in which case you can ask on Sports SE just fine, *or* on [metase]. This, however, is the dedicated child Meta of Stack Overflow itself. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An un-upvote is someone retracting their vote.

Normally votes are locked after a short grace period, but if you *edited* the post after a vote has been cast, the voter can retract the vote at any time afterwards. Sometimes that can be a **long** time afterwards.

The first post was [edited 22 hours after first posting](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/3905/revisions), for example. Your question was [edit twice in a 9 hour period](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/3876/revisions); in that case the voter changed their upvote to a downvote.