# Unupvote after grace period without an edit

Tags: discussion, voting

I thought that an unupvote is only possible within grace period or after an edit, see [Why this odd unupvote occurrence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251801/why-this-odd-unupvote-occurrence):

> Normally votes are locked after a short grace period, but if you edited the post after a vote has been cast, the voter can retract the vote at any time afterwards. Sometimes that can be a long time afterwards.

but I get an unupvote after some weeks without an edit:

[image: unupvote]

Has it something to do with the reversal in the same minute? Or is there another possibility to unupvote?

Answer (score 7):

This is a manual intervention, by a developer or perhaps a moderator. (Not sure if moderators can do this too).

I've had a similar case - I was serially downvoted, and not all downvotes were reversed by the script. I then alerted SO to the issue, and the remaining serial downvotes got "undownvote" afterwards.

Comment: Moderators cant do this, Only Community Managers can. (I think by developer, you meant Community Manager)