# What does the sudden unupvotes mean?

Tags: support

I've observed that so many unupvotes suddenly in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315800/chamila-wijayarathna?tab=reputation). What is the reason for this?

Comment: Very interesting. On old posts that were not even edited, so they should be locked.

Comment: Maybe a "user removed" glitch?

Comment: I observe the same with few of my friends profiles as well.

Comment: Then it sounds like some perceived shenanigans were reversed.

Comment: I sure I didn't edit most of these posts after I created them

Comment: Yeah if your friends have the same... Maybe it's more a voting irregularity that was resolved? I say we need a diamond mod...

Comment: Were you and your friends upvoting each other's answers?

Comment: From friends I meant others who usually answer questions in same tag as I do, however if that is the, it doesn't say unupvote, it has a different code as far as I remember

Comment: @Patrice: Voting reversals are marked differently.

Comment: Possibly related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336613/unupvote-after-grace-period-without-an-edit

Comment: @david Having a lot of "unupvote"s implies that they are *not* a part of the voting ring.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199946/are-unupvotes-serial-voting

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna I had samething on January 27th. Have not even touched the profile but sudden spike of unupvotings. so strange.

Comment: I've seen the same in the past 24 hours: 2 up-votes and an accepted answer on answers from mid-November.

Comment: @ShelanPerera my unupvotes are from jan 27th as well, and all are related to wso2, and both others I checked are also wso2 contributors. I think the voting ring they are talking about is something build around wso2

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A large voting ring had been invalidated at that time. Members of that ring voted for your posts, and those votes were invalidated.

Normally, this would be lumped together into "voting corrected". Perhaps the fact that you weren't labeled as being a member of the ring led to the manual invalidation of these votes showing up individually. The cause and result are the same, though.

Comment: [Voting rings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322114/voting-rings-how-to-handle-organized-groups-upvoting-each-other)! Haven't been aware of them.

Comment: Voting rings, Just like Onion Rings, but crispier and more spicy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think this unupvoting has happened around wso2 tag which I was following and answering questions, I checked several other contributors also and same has happened in their accounts as well. Also all my unupvotes are related to questions in wso2 tag. 
I can assure this is unintentional, may be it's because wso2 community is still not much big. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2

Comment: The obvious solution is to join the voting ring, in which case you won't get confusing notifications in your profile.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Can you explain please, what did you mean by joining the voting ring?

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna: I believe that Andras's comment was tongue-in-cheek.  It's not a good idea to join a voting ring.  If you had joined it, your penalty might well have been more severe.  As it stands, you have unfortunately lost some upvotes because the votes of the voting ring were cancelled — but that seems to be all.

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna as Jonathan said, I was only joking. Someone involved in the voting ring wouldn't get a bunch of confusing notifications about removal of upvotes. They would probably only get a single event of rep removal and a suspension.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing an obvious motive for this, but why would the members of a voting ring vote for the posts of a particular user *outside the ring* en masse?

Comment: Why can't these upvoting rings ever target me... you know... discreetly.

Comment: @MarkAmery Makes it look less suspicious. I assume a lot of users were affected by this, they just didn't make a meta post (yet).

Comment: @MarkAmery - It happens quite frequently with voting rings and sock puppets. I've personally lost large chunks of reputation when cleaning up sock puppet operations in tags I frequent. Sometimes, it's just that someone in the ring tells others that they like someone's posts and they should vote for them (or uses their puppets to do so). The timing of the votes and the physical location of the users involved does seem to indicate active coordination here, so I can see why these votes might have been invalidated.